# No Rubik's cube can be solved in 13 moves

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, rubiks-cube

I've seen a very interesting paper/article few hours ago where it says: there is NO permutation of the Rubiks Cube from where there is a solution in 13 moves, but no solution in less moves.
i.e., there is no position with distance 13 from the identity.
But I cannot find the paper! Can someone help me find or does someone know the paper?

Or are there similar, simpler examples of other groups where all elements can be reached by combining the generators, but there is no element with a certain distance?

David

Comment: Out of curiosity you are saying even if you have the identity cube and make $13$ random movements, you are always able to solve the resulting cube in less moves than $13$?

Comment: Exactly! That's the point.

Comment: To be clear, if there are positions that require more than $13$ moves to solve, then there are positions that require exactly $13$ moves.  Start from a position that requires $13+N$ moves, and then make $N$ optimal moves.  Where are you now?

Comment: You probably misremembered or misunderstood the article. The prime $13$ does not divide the order of the Rubik's cube group, so there is no element in the group of order $13$. That does not mean that there is no position that takes 13 moves to solve, but it means that there is no move sequence that when applied 13 times on a solved cube will then return the cube to its solved state (except those that already do so after being applied once).

Comment: True, that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure who told you that but according to https://cube20.org/ there are 531,653,418,284,628 positions solvable in exactly 13 moves (and no less).

Comment: Of course, I've totally missed that...